# Confirm con JQuery

Tags: jquery

Estoy teniendo bastantes dudas y problemas a la hora de utilizar el **confirm** con *JQuery*, debido a que no me muestra por consola lo indicado.

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```js
$('#notificaciones')
  .on('click', function() {
    confirm("Desea permitir las notificaciones en esta página?", function(respuesta) {
      if (respuesta == 'granted') {
        console.log("Has pulsado confirmar");
      } else {
        console.log("Has pulsado cancelar");
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>
    Prueba
  </title>
  <link href="css/estilo1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js">
  </script>
  </link>
  </meta>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="notificaciones">
           Notificaciones
        </button>
  <script src="js/jquery.js">
  </script>
  </input>
</body>

</html>
```

No se porqué no me funciona, pero si alguien sabe como hacerlo, me serviría de ayuda. Si puede ser, sin utilizar Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, en tu HTML hay un `input` huérfano (aparece un cierre, pero la apertura del mismo no se ve). Corrige eso, dé error o no, pues estaríamos ante un HTML inválido que podría ser problemático.

Por otro lado, [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) devolvería `true` o `false`, como bien dice la documentación:

> `result` es un valor booleano indicando si se ha pulsado `Aceptar` o
> `Cancelar` (`Aceptar` devuelve `true`).

Entonces no entiendo por qué te complicas tanto para esa comparación, o por qué intentas comparar contra el valor `granted` ¿?

Así debería funcionar:

```js
$('#notificaciones').on('click', function() {
  if (confirm("Desea permitir las notificaciones en esta página?")) {
    console.log("Has pulsado aceptar");
  } else {
    console.log("Has pulsado cancelar");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="notificaciones">
           Notificaciones
        </button>
```

O, más simple aún, con un ternario:

```js
$('#notificaciones').on('click', function() {
  var mStatus = confirm("Desea permitir las notificaciones en esta página?") ?
    "Has pulsado aceptar" : "Has pulsado cancelar";
  console.log(mStatus);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="notificaciones">
           Notificaciones
        </button>
```

Comment: Gracias @A. Cedano. Ya lo he corregido y me funciona correctamente de ambas maneras. He empleado la ternaria, ya que nunca lo había visto y me parece interesante.

Comment: @ShadowZ me alegro de que te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El error es que le estas enviando un callback y este te retorna un true en caso de que el usuario haya dado aceptar o confirmar y un false en caso de que selecciono cancelar,

la manera correcta es esta para trabajar con alert confirm.

```js
function confirmacion(){
    let confirma = confirm( "Desea permitir las notificaciones en esta página?");

    if ( confirma) {
      console.log( "Has pulsado confirmar" );
    } else {
      console.log( "Has pulsado cancelar" );
    }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="confirmacion()">confirmacion</button>
```

Documentación de la función [confirm](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

Comment: Me ha funcionado también tu forma de hacerlo, por lo que también es válida.